# Help to finish proof that every closed and bounded interval of $\mathbb R$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'd like to understand the proof that every closed and bounded interval of $\mathbb R$ is compact.

**Proof.** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an open covering of $[a, b]$ and define:

$$A:=\{c\in [a, b]: (\exists n \in \mathbb Z^+)(\exists C_1, \ldots, C_n \in \mathcal C)([a, c]\subset C_1\cup\cdots \cup C_n)\}$$

Since $a\in [a, b]$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is a covering of $[a, b]$ there is $C\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $a\in C$. Hence,

$$[a, a]=\{a\}\subset C$$
and therefore $a\in A$, that is, $A\neq \phi$. Since $A\subset [a, b]$, $A$ is bounded above by $b$ and consequently there exists

$$s:=\sup A$$

and

$$s\leq b.$$

Furtheremore, since $a\in A$, we have $a\leq s$ for $s$ is an upper bound of $A$. This tells us that

$$s\in [a, b].$$

Now since $\mathcal{C}$ is an open covering of $[a, b]$, there is $C\in \mathcal{C}$ open such that $s\in C$. By the defintion of open set, one can find $\delta>0$ such that $$(s-\delta, s+\delta)\subset C.$$

Next, by the definition of supremum, there is  $c\in (s-\delta, s]\cap A$. Hence,  $c\in [a, b]$ and there are $C_1, \ldots, C_n\in \mathcal{C}$ such that
$$[a, c]\subset C_1\cup \cdots \cup C_n.$$  But, for every $d\in [s, s+\delta)$ it follows that

$$s-\delta<c\leq s\leq d<s+\delta.$$ In particular,

$$[c, d]\subset (s-\delta, s+\delta)\subset C\quad \textrm{and}\quad [a, d]=[a, c]\cup [c,d ]\subset C_1\cup\cdots \cup C_n\cup C.$$
This tells us that $$\forall d\in [a, b]\cap [s, s+\delta)\Rightarrow d\in A.$$
All that is left to show is that $b\in [s, s+\delta)$ for this will imply $b\in [a, b]\cap [s, s+\delta)$ and therefore $b\in A$. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve forgotten that $s=\sup A$. All you have to do is pick any $d\in(s,s+\delta)\cap[a,b]$: as you’ve shown, $d\in A$, but $d>s$, contradicting the choice of $s$. Thus, there cannot be such a $d$. What does that tell you about $s$?

Comment: I understand your argument that there can't be such $d\in (s, s+\delta)\cap [a, b]$ but I can't see what it tells us about $s$. As a matter of fact, I know $s\in [s, s+\delta) \cap [a, b]$, hence $s\in A$, and so what?

Comment: I know this should imply $s=b$, but I still can't figure that out.

Comment: @Ptf    $(s, s+\delta) \cap [a,b]= \phi$ and $s\in [a,b] $ simultaneously imply $s=b$

Comment: @PtF: (Sorry; I was away for a bit.) If $s<b$, then $(s,s+\delta\cap[a,b]\ne\varnothing$, so there is such a $d$. We’ve just shown that this leads to a contradiction, so it cannot be the case that $s<b$. Obviously $s\le b$, so $s=b$. Now you just have to verify that $s\in A$.